# When did Walter Benjamin say "We collect books in the belief that we are preserving them when in fact it is the books that preserve their collector"?

Tags: reference-request, quote, benjamin, sources

In for instance this [source](https://www.quoteswave.com/picture-quotes/407089), it is stated that Walter Benjamin once said or wrote the following:

> "We collect books in the belief that we are preserving them when in fact it is the books that preserve their collector."

However, I cannot find the source of this quote. Was it stated in his essay "Unpacking My Library," or perhaps somewhere else?